# Write Spring Specification to filter unrelated tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am working on a project Spring and Java, generated using JHipster. I want to filter on table that doesn't have a direct relationship with another.

My purpose is almost asked in a previous similar question 
[Write Spring Specification with multiple inner join & other conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672270/write-spring-specification-with-multiple-inner-join-other-conditions/65827731)

But in my case , I ve two unrelated entities :

 **Consultant** (id : Long , FullName : string , profileRank : Enum of string )

 **Rank** (id : Long , level : Enum of string , rate : Double )

```
 Consultant                         |        Rank
                                    | 
id | FullName | profileRank         |        id | level    | rate      
1  | aaaaa    | 'ONE'               |        1  | 'ONE'    | 1
2  | bbbbbb   | 'THREE'             |        2  | 'TWO'    | 2
3  | cccccc   | 'FOUR'              |        3  | 'THREE'  | 3
4  | dddddd   | 'THREE'             |        4  | 'FOUR'   | 4
```

I want to filter **consultant** list by **rate** using **level** 
Example : get consultants with rate greater than 3

```
Expected result  
id | FullName | profileRank      
3  | cccccc   | 'FOUR'
```

I ve searched in documentation and many articles without get it to work please how to achieve that .

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a specification for your case.

1. Fetch all the ranks with levels and rates
2. Filter these values and keep only the ones greater than 3 (step 1 and 2 can be combined). The result will be a `List<Rank>` that contains only `FOUR` rank
3. `list.stream(rank => rank.level).collect(toList())`
4. The result of step 3 will be passed to a repository method like `List<Consultant> findByProfileRankIn(List<String> levelNames)`

Another alternative would be joins something like this [Joining tables without relation using JPA criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639132/joining-tables-without-relation-using-jpa-criteria)

If you still want a spec that's also possible. [Spring Data Join with Specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168108/spring-data-join-with-specifications)